# MongoDB Realm: environment value exists but is undefined inside Realm Function

Tags: mongodb, realm, mongodb-realm

I am referencing an environment value from a Realm function as instructed [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/values-and-secrets/access-a-value/#reference-a-value-in-a-function): `context.values.get("appTwilioNumber")`

I confirmed `appTwilioNumber` exists in our project: [image: appTwilioNumber variable is defined for all environments] and that our project is assigned an environment: [image]

Yet, when I call `console.log('twilioNumberForEnv:', context.values.get("appTwilioNumber"));` in our Realm function, I get `twilioNumberForEnv: undefined`.

EDIT 1: I have more info now--I logged out and logged back in (in case of multi-user sync issues), then exported my app from the Realm UI and the values folder is empty. Not sure if that is a separate bug, but updating in case this info is useful.

EDIT 2: the environment values are stored under environment, not under values. Edit 1 was a red herring. I do see appTwilioNumber in the exported app, but it still returns undefined in the Realm functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow... Mongo's documentation might be off.

In another function, I found this: `context.environment.values.anotherEnvValue` instead of `context.values.get("appTwilioNumber")` . So I updated my code to `context.environment.values.appTwilioNumber`, and it worked.

I did a CMD-f on both https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/values-and-secrets/define-environment-values/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/values-and-secrets/access-a-value/ for ".environment", and it isn't on either page.

I'll follow up with Mongo, but please use `context.environment.values.YOURENVVALUE` instead of `context.values.get("YOURENVVALUE")` if you encounter this issue.

Comment: The correct command can be found under functions: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/functions/context/#mongodb-method-context.environment.values . Perhaps the docs for values and secrets didn't get updated.